# Android 9 - ADB: set-home-activity cannot be home on user 0

Tags: android, adb, android-launcher

My goal is to run my android app in kiosk mode. In general this works but additionally I want to set the app as standard launcher using adb so the user is not asked on every reboot which launcher app should be used.

So at first I send
`pm set-device-owner myPackage/.Receiver"` to set the app as device owner for the kiosk mode.
After this I send `pm set-home-activity myPackage/.MainActivity"` to set it as main activity. But the command returns always with `"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component ComponentInfo{myPackage/myPackage.MainActivity} cannot be home on user 0"` and I don't know why.
When I reboot the phone I get the selection which Launcher should be used and there I can select the built-in launcher and my app. When I select my app there, it works without problems.

I tried to completely deactivate the built-in launcher by sending `pm disable-user --user 0 com.android.launcher3`. This actually works immediately and my app is set as home app in kiosk mode. But I do not want to do this because then I have no app drawer etc, when I leave the kiosk of my app.

All I want to do is the selection of the launcher app after reboot via adb without rebooting the device.